# What happens to left-over energy in atomic excitations?

Tags: energy-conservation, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, discrete

The question relates to quantization of energy.
As we know, to make an electron jump to a higher energy level, a discrete amount of energy must be given to it. If the energy provided is less than the energy required for the jump, the electron doesn't jump to a higher orbit.

My question then is, what happens if there is energy for, say 2.5 jumps. The electron should jump up two energy levels, but what happens to the 0.5 "jumps" worth of energy?

Also, if nothing can interact with it (as no electrons can make the jump), has it been permanently lost?

Comment: The answer involves quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanical transitions. For  your "if there is energy for, say 2.5 jumps" the answer is that in a quantum mechanical system, nothing will happen.  either the photon has an energy within the width of the energy states, when it can excite the electron to a higher state, or the photo goes through , (or may interact/scatter  with the atom, no energy level transitions)

Answer (score 9):

> My question then is, what happens if there is energy for, say 2.5 jumps. The electron should jump up two energy levels, but what happens to the 0.5 "jumps" worth of energy?

A photon with energy between two neighboring transitions will not be absorbed. The material will be transparent to that wavelength.

> Also, if nothing can interact with it (as no electrons can make the jump), has it been permanently lost?

No. The energy stays with the photon as it leaves the transparent material.

Comment: Dale is correct for atoms - absorption happens only at exactly at the transition energy, and you see absorption lines. If you're curious, then, how come we have opaque  materials which are opaque to all visible light or other bands of frequencies, well, in more complex materials such as molecules or crystals, the photon may be absorbed to cause vibrations in the material, not (or not only) in electrons in an atom. The result can be wide absorption bands.

Comment: @NadavHar'El Nice comment! I was wondering just that.

Comment: @NadavHar'El And of course, the thing that makes metals metals and plasma plasma - both have free electrons that are not bound to any orbital states, and thus have _very_ wide bands for absorbing (and emitting) photons.

Comment: I'm grateful for the above comments as this answer left me wondering how much light gets absorbed at all if only a limited set of very specific energies can be absorbed across a wide continuum of possible energy values!